# Windows Phone 8 - WebBrowser Control does not perform ajax refresh

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am using a webbrowser control in my app.  The control does not perform at all with ajax refresh panels, almost like it is preventing the partial-refresh to load.  Is there something I am missing with this control?  I really need it to work as part of my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are disabled by default on the `WebBrowser` control. Did you set the `IsScriptEnabled` to `true`?

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```